# How to handle union types returned from API?

Tags: swift, codable, decodable

I'm working with an API that returns a JSON, and one of the fields is a union type.  If the field has a value, its type is `number`.  If there is no value, it's an empty `string`.  So two possible responses are:

```
{
  "phone_number": 49238382
}

{
  "phone_number": ""
}
```

Is there a simple way to get this to work with Codable?  Or do I need to write my own decoder?

I also don't know which fields will behave like this.  That is, I don't know if a number field will return `""` for an empty value or `null`.  So I would need to handle it in a generic way.

Comment: Blame the owner of the service for that mess.